# Nginx rtmp module (m3u8) to play unlocally?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nginx, rtmp, m3u8

Need some help with this, please be kind ^^"

So .. Nginx + Obs create a m3u8 that I'm able to play locally at http://ipaddress/name.m3u8

Now, **I would like to put this m3u8 online**.

Two ways that I've thought of :

1 - **Set Nginx to write/erase the m3u8 and .ts files on a mysql or another cloud** (to play it at http://domain.whatever/name.m3u8)

2 - **Make the folder where the m3u8 and ts files are written available through the internet**.

---

My questions :

How to put this m3u8 on the internet ? 
How to proceed ? 
Is it even possible to do it like I just said ?

I'd like a free way to do it.. as it's for educationnal purposes..

Sorry for my bad english but I'm french.. ^^"

Thank you !

Comment: Option 2 is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out how..

Redirection (internet provider's management tool) from the port nginx uses (not the "listen" one, the other one) to the pc ipv4 address and then use public address to access the stream http://publicaddress:port/folder/file.m3u8

It should also work to access mp4 or else from through internet, usefull to be used as a remote storage (as long as nginx is working, the folder is shared.. so you should be able to access anything in that folder from that url)

Though, still one thing : crossdomain access with m3u8. But it works so... i don't care for now :)

Thanks to szatmary for your answer